# Array or array element in C?

Tags: c, arrays, element

I'm reading a book about C programming, and I'm not sure whether there is an error in the book or not. Its about arrays and has the following array example:

[image]
Then it says:

> The following statements sets all the elements in row 2 of array to zero:
>   
>   `for( column = 0; column <= 3; column++)
>    a[ 2 ][ column ] = 0;`
>
> The preceding for statement is equivalent to the assignment statements:
>        `a[ 2 ][ 0 ] = 0;
>        a[ 2 ][ 1 ] = 0;
>        a[ 2 ][ 2 ] = 0;
>        a[ 2 ][ 3 ] = 0;`

Shouldn't it say "The following statements sets all the elements in row 1 to zero"?. Because if I say a[ 3 ] I am talking about the row 2, if I say a[ 2 ] I am talking about row 1 and if I say a[ 1 ] I am talking about row 0.

Comment: _"Shouldn't it say "The following statements sets all the elements in row 1" instead of 2"_ - Do you mean, _"in row **3**"_? Nevertheless, I don't think this is a mistake. They may use zero-based counting too.

Comment: The book's text is speaking in terms of 0 indexed to match the code.

Comment: The book is consistent with how C indexes *and its own figure*.

Comment: "if I say a[ 1 ] I am talking about row 0." - no, `a[0]` talks about row `0`. Just as in the diagram in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and zero-based indexing to reference array indices. The description you've provided of what is in the book is consistent with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the book means there are actually 3 rows in the array: #0, #1, #2. They are modifying row #2 which is the third row.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it say "The following statements sets all the elements in row 1 to zero".

**No**. It shouldn't. In C, array indexing starts from `0`. In the same book at page number 196 author said that:

> The first element in every array is the zeroth element. Thus, the first element of array c is referred to as c[0], ...

Answer (score 0):

The author seems to be counting from zero, just like how arrays start from index 0 instead of index 1 in c.

As one of the comments asks: Do you mean to wonder if the author should say "row 3" instead of "row 2" since the row is indexed by 2 and so is the third row in the array?

Anyways, There is not an error in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Which row is "row 2" is a matter of convention. The picture you posted establishes that convention pretty clearly and unambiguously: rows are numbered from 0. This means that `a[0][i]` refers to elements in row 0, while `a[2][i]` refers to elements in row 2. For that reason I don't see anything wrong in that quote.

Moreover, I don't see how it could possibly be "row 1" under any meaningful convention. I wouldn't be surprised to see someone call it "row 3", but not "row 1"... Why "row 1"? Your assertion *"if I say a[ 3 ] I am talking about the row 2, if I say a[ 2 ] I am talking about row 1 and if I say a[ 1 ] I am talking about row 0"* suffers from the same problem. I don't see any logic in it.